# Use MacBook Air as a monitor for Win7 Desktop PC

Tags: macbook-pro

Not sure if this is the right place to ask: but i have a Win7 machine and i want to save apartment space by foregoing the monitor, and use my existing MacBook Air screen as a temporary monitor when i reboot my Win7 machine.

Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-is/ht3924) notebooks do not support Target Display mode.

However, if you run any kind of VNC software on your Windows machine you can use the Windows desktop from your Mac using the Screen Sharing application. No additional software is needed on the Mac end.

If your Windows machine won't boot to the desktop the VNC software will not run, so you will need a temporary monitor here. And you will need to install the VNC program somehow.

In short, Windows computers really expect to have a keyboard, monitor and mouse connected.